# Trying to understand why I am getting a time delay of 2 seconds post get and pre Action, found with Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, EF5, C#, Razor, SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am analysing an Action which does some DML via LINQ and EF. No real issues, takes about 1 second. I am using Glimpse to monitor the application. However I notice that Server time is 3 seconds, and the controller Action time is 1 second, so 2 seconds are going missing. It is as if it is taking 2 seconds to instantiate the Controller class etc. The application is warmed up.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

and here:

[image]

So summary of metrics is roughly:

Total  4 sec
  Client 1 sec
  Server 3 sec
    PreAction something ???? 2 sec
    Action 1 sec

This happens with the dev web server as well as on Win7/IIS with Precompiled code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but if it was the JIT compiler it would only happen on the first run. It happens every run which is bizarre.

Comment: Might it be Glimpse drawback?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich, You might be right. Just tried it with Glimpse turned off, and it goes a lot quicker, basically 1 sec I would guess. I wonder if there is usually a penalty like this for Glimpse. OK if known, as the information it provides within the code is invaluable. However I would be a little nervous on running it in production, but probably OK as browser specific to turn on via Glimpse.axd, I believe.

Comment: sounds good. So, I will post it as an answer just in case it is correct.

Comment: OK Will do. I have noticed penalties on other pages of between 2-4x Action execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a Glimpse drawback. Try to run application with and without it and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks for this. It would be interesting to hear from other Glimpse experts whether this is expected behaviour. Will post question specifically on this.

Comment: I have used Glimpse quite a lot and I have never had a 2 second discrepancy.

Comment: Time delays like this are definitely not expected from Glimpse. Some times we have had people report time delays in cases where they are passing EF models that have lazy loaded properties to the view or in some complex model binding cases? To try and narrow this down, could you try disabling the `Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.ModelBinderInspector`. If that doesn't make a difference try disabling tabs one by one to find the cause. Would love to find the root cause in your case.

Comment: @anthonyv, thanks for the comments. Looking further at other pages, it is a time penalty of order of magnitude greater(2-4x) than the Action execution time. So if Action takes 100ms, then the extra might be about 400ms, not too seconds. In my example the action was taking about 800ms, hence the 2 secs which is 2.5X. I will do the testing as suggested, and feedback.