# Glimpse seems to add a time penalty of between 2 and 4 of Action execution process time, Is this expected?

Tags: glimpse

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, C#, Razor, EF5, SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am upto to date with Glimpse and have installed:

```
Glimpse.ADO
Glimpse.ASP.NET
Glimpse.Core
Glimpse.EF5
Glimpse.MVC3
Glimpse for Elmah
```

I have noticed that Glimpse adds between 2 and 4 times the Execution time to the total time, and this time penalty is recorded under the "Server" category. So if I have an Action that performs some DML via LINQ which takes 1 sec, then the total server time is 3 sec. When I turn Glimpse off via Glimpse.axd, the time reduces to 1 sec.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so why?

The important bit is knowing that it is due to Glimpse and not my code, especially as Glimpse provides such great information for the Action Code.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865711/trying-to-understand-why-i-am-getting-a-time-delay-of-2-seconds-post-get-and-pre)

Comment: Time delays like this are definitely not expected from Glimpse. Some times we have had people report time delays in cases where they are passing EF models that have lazy loaded properties to the view or in some complex model binding cases? To try and narrow this down, could you try disabling the `Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.ModelBinderInspector`. If that doesn't make a difference try disabling tabs one by one to find the cause. Would love to find the root cause in your case.

Comment: @anthonyv. As per other post, will do the testing and feedback. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @anthonyv, I have disabled the tabs one by one, as requested, and the offending tab seems to be Glimpse.Ado (1.7.3). Thoughts?? Also I noticed that this tab operated very slowly when clicked to list out the SQL statements. Perhaps I need to reinstall it ???

Comment: Very reassuring that I have found this, as I can disable this tab when working in live.